# Dataflow/Beam reading from HBase in chunks

Tags: hbase, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to understand how to ingest hbase database into Apache Beam/Dataflow in batches of 10 records.

So far I've tried something like below which provides me triggers for each row.

```
PCollection<KV<Integer,String>> records =  p.apply("read",HBaseIO.read()
                .withConfiguration(conf)
                .withTableId("Data")
                .withScan(scan))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Result, KV<Integer,String>>() {
                    @DoFn.ProcessElement
                    public void process(ProcessContext c){
                        Long ts = Bytes.toLong(c.element().getValue(Bytes.toBytes("timestamp"),Bytes.toBytes("timestamp")));
                        System.out.println(Long.toString(ts));
                        Integer pid = Bytes.toInt(c.element().getValue(Bytes.toBytes("patientid"),Bytes.toBytes("patientid")));
                        c.outputWithTimestamp(KV.of(pid,Long.toString(ts)),new Instant(ts));

                    }
                    @Override
                    public Duration getAllowedTimestampSkew(){
                        return Duration.standardDays(1);
                    }
                }));
```

But what I need is to group them in 10 sequential rows and then run downstream pipelines.

I've tried to group the into windows using Windowing, where as I'm continuously losing data points.(Not included in any window or  some windows never getting completed even for a prepared dataaset)

Please provide your views and ideas to address this sort of issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why you want to group rows into batches of 10? Does it matter which particular rows end up in the same group?

Comment: Actually what i want is to ingest ordered dataset into dataflow/beam and trigger a window for every 10 seconds. (Using original event timestamp). But after numerous tries, i see lot of incomplete windows and some windows not triggering at all even the original source had all the data in order.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps your windowing or triggering strategies are not set up right. Could you provide more details, e.g. your code, a Dataflow job ID, and the expected behavior and actual behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache Beam Execution](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/execution-model/) model says:

> Beam pipelines often focus on “[embarassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/embarrassingly_parallel)” problems. Because of this, the APIs emphasize processing elements in parallel, which makes it difficult to express actions like “assign a sequence number to each element in a PCollection”. This is intentional as such algorithms are much more likely to suffer from scalability problems.

Because of this, you should not make assumptions about ordering in PCollections.

Comment: I was trying to to read 10 next rows in a database into one single object in a PCollection. ie. Single element of PCollection will contain 10 row elements.
Ideally this batching should be done by windowing, which has appeared to be inconsistent at this point.